# Bing cognitive search, actual site in url, not bing redirection

Tags: bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services, web-search, bing-search

Is there a way that the result link to show the exact link, not the bing redirecting one?

For example ins there a way in bing cognitive search to put href the actual link instead of a redirection?

```
`"value": [
 {
     "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v5/#WebPages.0",
     "name": "<b>Burrito Recipes</b> - Allrecipes.com",
     "url": "http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=4BE4CA19570B4740ABE2B85782727544&CI......",
     "displayUrl": "all<b>recipes</b>.com/<b>recipes</b>/1216",
     "snippet": "<b>Burrito Recipes</b> ...",
     "deepLinks": [
         {
             "name": "Mexican",
             "url": "http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=4BE4CA19570B4740ABE2BF...",
             "snippet": "Mexican Recipes Find ..."
         }
      ]`
```

so the url to be the actual link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'r=' query parameter in the url to get the exact url where the redirection is pointed to. A sample bing url looks like this

```
"url": "http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=584DA9A5C8B245DDA12848B177BAF817&CID=138CDEBD227860443797D43D239D616C&rd=1&h=0UIFjW9hoNBrd0LFRhopxM1IDwbKCHvSc-z-FdLfyMQ&v=1&r=http%3a%2f%2fallrecipes.com%2frecipes%2f1216%2fworld-cuisine%2flatin-american%2fmexican%2fmain-dishes%2fburritos%2f&p=DevEx,5066.1"
```

Here,

```
r=http%3a%2f%2fallrecipes.com%2frecipes%2f1216%2fworld-cuisine%2flatin-american%2fmexican%2fmain-dishes%2fburritos%2f
```

Note that the url is encoded. Perform url decoding if required. All this can be done using the following Java code.

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public static String getExactUrl(String url) {
    Map<String, String> queryParams = getQueryParamsMap(url);
    return queryParams.getOrDefault("r", url);
}

public static Map<String, String> getQueryParamsMap(String url) {
    Map<String, String> queryParamsMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
        List<NameValuePair> queryParams = uriBuilder.getQueryParams();
        queryParamsMap = queryParams.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NameValuePair::getName, NameValuePair::getValue));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return queryParamsMap;
}
```

Comment: Cool, I see that, but wouldn't this breach bing terms of service? what's your experience in this?

Comment: The Bing Search API Use and Display Requirements at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/useanddisplayrequirements does mention that you **must not modify content of results (other than to reformat them in a way that does not violate any other requirement);** as they use the redirection url for data gathering.

Answer (score 0):

The only way we found is to just remove `<b>` and `</b>` from `displayUrl`...

Comment: Yes, but then that is the front end URL; to be displayed, it might not be the full URL path though....